# Android HttpClient identifies as mobile device

Tags: android, header, httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` together with `HttpGet` to download a few websites. They're detecting that the website is accessed from a mobile device through the http headers and they're consequently returning the mobile version of the respective page.

I want to download the normal version, so I have to stop `HttpClient` from telling the site that it's a mobile device. How do I do it?

I've tried:

```
HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(httpClient.getParams(), "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

But the mobile version still loads, so there must be few more headers that I need to overwrite.

Comment: If you do follow Rich's advice, make sure to add what else you have to change. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit an endpoint that spits out the HTTP headers and then you can inspect whatever is being sent from your code and override whatever is necessary.  I googled and found this (among others):

http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php

Comment: I've just tried it and it's weird. It shows that it's sending only "Host", "Connection" and "User-agent" headers. And still the website is able to detect it's a mobile device...